# Address Verification Service

Tags: balanced-payments

During testing of tokenization when we supply a postal code with a card we get

- attribute postal_code_check passed

The documentation states "Supplying a postal_code during tokenization initiates the AVS check."

So in our live marketplace, can we verify AVS as part of the tokenization process or does the testing environment nor match the live one?

To give an example; when I tokenize a card and then check the card object I can read

```
postal_code_check: passed
security_code_check: passed
```

I know the security_code_check should not be getting done until an "authenticated operation" is performed so it should not be happening here, worrying.  Where as postal_code_check may be "initiated" during tokenization.

Comment: "can we verify AVS as part of the tokenization process or does the testing environment nor match the live one?" - I think you need to email their support directly, sorry: we're not going to know. And I know they [point people here for 'technical questions'](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/#support) on their support page, but I don't see any evidence of their staff answering questions here in the past few months.

Comment: You are right about going directly to them, I do have a time zone clash for IRC and although I could email a shared answer would help other people.  So if I get a response I will post here.  There is the possibility that another customer has already got the answer to this and will share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a test environment, Balanced does not call out to the credit card networks at all. Therefore, it cannot verify postal codes or CVV. Please look at https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/resources/#test-credit-card-numbers, which provides test credit cards numbers for simulating different scenarios.

Comment: Thank you we are using v1.0 not 1.1, I will check if those test numbers work.  The return of postal_code_check passed during tokenization is contra-logical to not doing the test.  If we are going to check a card pre-authorisation and it already is incorrectly marked passed, the code has to cater for this danger.

Comment: If you are doing a new integration, why are you using 1.0? Use 1.1 - it's better and less likely to be shut down in the future.

Comment: Because it is not a new integration, migration is not straightforward and Balanced have told us that they will continue to support 1.0.